# Why does find take so long

Tags: find

When using find to search for a file name (locally mounted drives only) why does it take so long? Is it searching more than just the catalog?

Comment: Your a little short on information to be able to even guess an answer.  What is the OS ?  What is the find/search method? Are the power settings set to allow the storage to sleep (Turn off hard drive)?  What are you seeing when it takes the time?  What is the size of the drives, and quantity and type of file items?   Please edit your question to include way more information, or pictures. My psycic powers for seeing everything your doing on your computer are running low.

Answer (score 1):

You may be searching file names and contents, not just file names in non indexed locations. This would cause the search to take longer.

To change this, if you are (for example) searching Local Disk (C:), go to that disk folder, press alt, and select Tools from the toolbar that appears. Then go to 'Folder Options' > 'Search' > and ensure the 'What to search' setting at the top is set to 'In indexed locations, search file names and contents...'